# Do anyone know the reason why Android WebView loading partial content?

Tags: android, url, caching, android-webview

In my application am showing contents with URL www.domain_name.com/content?id=5513 . Each content have different ids. When phone have data then it loads WebView from network, otherwise it loads from cache. My issue is that webview loads partially for every URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was backend issue, where pages are loading dynamically to single page. Changed dynamic page to single page.